# Understanding Compilation and Dynamic Typing with Nuitka Compiler and LLVM-IR?

Tags: python, compilation, llvm, dynamic-typing, nuitka

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am trying to better understand compilation and dynamic typing, and I have a specific question regarding the Nuitka Compiler. As far as I understand, Nuitka compiles Python code into C, and I'm curious about how it handles functions defined without explicit types in their arguments.

Here's my primary question: When a function is defined without explicit types for its arguments in Python, and Nuitka compiles the code into C, how are these untyped arguments handled in the resulting C code, which typically requires typed arguments?

Furthermore, I'm interested in exploring possibilities beyond Nuitka and wondering how one might achieve a similar result with other compilers, specifically in the context of LLVM-IR. How could a function with non-typed arguments be compiled into LLVM-IR?

Disclaimer: ChatGPT was used to format and make the question more readable

Comment: Have a look at this section of the documentation: https://nuitka.net/doc/developer-manual.html#current-state The relevant part starts with "Regarding types..."